# Rep increase after deleting downvoted answer?

Tags: support

I recently deleted an answer of mine that had been downvoted, since in retrospect the answer really should have been downvoted and was not worth keeping. Anyway, I was surprized when my rep increased by 2 after the deletion.

I thought that downvotes always counted, even on deleted answers? And it probably should count, to encourage good answers in the first place :)

Comment: So what's the question/issue? Yep - deletions will refund lost rep, in the same way that you would lose rep if it were upvoted prior to deletion.

Comment: This is the first time, I see anybody complain about a refunded downvote. ;-).

Comment: Well, maybe there is no issue then. I thought that deleted rep was never refunded and this might be a bug. Doesn't the refund encourage poor answers, since I can just post a low quality answer, and if it is downvoted I can always delete it later?

Comment: @JustinEthier: get too many downvotes and delete too many of your answers, and you might very well find yourself automatically banned from answering altogether.

Comment: @Mat - Agreed and I'm certainly not advocating such behavior, I was just surprised the rep was refunded at all.

Comment: I guess this works well with people who, like you, do care about the quality of their posts & the site in general - no point in "penalizing" you permanently for one or two errors here or there. For people who don't care, the auto-ban should solve the problem.

Comment: Good point - thanks for your time!